# Latex code for subcaption of image?

Tags: graphics

I will display some output images in my paper which generated from two data sets using same algorithm. The algorithms have some steps and the results of each step will display. I need  the latex code [image: The image will be display like this in pdf file]

Comment: ...we need a show of effort.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Pleas help us to help you. Your question is not very clear: (i) does images had  to be numbered, (ii) are images is should be organized as subimages of figure, (iii) is document two or one column type . You should show us, what you try so far.

Comment: The caption off the image like Figure 1. Birds Images from Different Data set, then there will be another caption 1.1 Data set1, 1.2 Data set2, under data set1 there will be captions like a. M1, b. M2,c.M3. Your code has fulfilled partially. But I still can't capable to give the master caption

Answer (score 2):

As starting point can serve one of my old answers to similar question (sorry, I forgot the question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]%\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Bird A}
        \label{fig:bird-a}
    \end{subfigure}
\hfill%\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Bird B}
    \label{fig:bird-a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill%\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\hsize]{example-image-c}
    \caption{Bird C}
    \label{fig:bird-a}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Birds}
    \label{fig:birds-1}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

For more help you need to consider my comment above ...

Comment: If I omit `\centering`, than I should use `\hfill` instead `\hfil`. This is here sensible since for the space between images is left only `0.1\textwidth`.